# SimpleMembership with FederatedAuthetication using ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: claims-based-identity, simplemembership

An Application using SimpleMembership (as the MVC template internet application of VS 2012) and another application that uses ClaimsPrincipal with FederatedAuthetication.

Some One has experience on the authentication an authorization process using SimpleMembership and use FederatedAuthetication since the step:

a) When Login use websecuroty.Login (from SimpleMembership)

or

b) use FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie

where is the place to join this both two SimpleMembership with System.Security.Claims

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this approach to bridge both worlds

http://brockallen.com/2012/09/05/integrating-claims-and-oauthwebsecurity/

Answer (score 0):

Also, FWIW, I put together a stand-alone sample of using OAuth2 and then collecting the returned profile information and using that for claims. It's separate from the prior example @woloski linked, but both are trying to do the same thing:

http://brockallen.com/2012/10/26/integrating-claims-and-oauth2/